# My ban command gives an error in permissions manager

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

For some reason this permissions line in my ban command is not working. Here is the error I get while trying to run my bot:

```
if(!message.guild.member(message.author).hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {return message.channel.send(
            ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '!'
```

Here is also my ban command:

```js
const { MessageEmbed, Message } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');
const config = require('../config.json');
const CatLoggr = require('cat-loggr');

// Functions
const log = new CatLoggr();

module.exports = {
    name: 'ban', // Command name (can be different from the file name)
    description: 'Bans a member.', // Command description displays in the help command

         if(!message.guild.member(message.author).hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {return message.channel.send(
                new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(config.color.red)
                .setTitle('Error occurred!')
                .setDescription('You do not have permission to use this command!')
                .setFooter(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, size: 64 }))
                .setTimestamp()
            )
        };

        //get first mentioned member
        const member = message.mentions.users.first()
        if (!member) return message.channel.send(
                new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(config.color.red)
                .setTitle('Missing parameters!')
                .setDescription('Please mention the member you want to ban!')
                .setFooter(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, size: 64 }))
                .setTimestamp()
            )

        //Convert member to a user so we can use it
        const user = message.guild.member(member)

        try {

            //Ban user
            user.ban()
            message.channel.send(
                new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(config.color.red)
                .setTitle('Member Banned!')
                .setDescription(`\`${member.username}\ has been banned!`)
                .setFooter(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, size: 64 }))
                .setTimestamp()
               )
            
        } catch (err) {

            console.log(err)
            return message.channel.send(
                new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(config.color.red)
                .setTitle('Error occurred!')
                .setDescription(`Couldn't ban \`${member.username}\` make sure I have the right roles!`)
                .setFooter(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, size: 64 }))
                .setTimestamp()
            )
```

I tried rewriting the code and also deleting and adding some parts, but still doesn't work.
If you can help me solve this that would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Voted to close it as a typo. It seems you've deleted a line by accident. That if statement should be inside a method in your exported object. Some name it `run()`, others `execute()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in normal JS code instead of variables to `module.exports`. You have to put it somewhere else, like a function that runs when the command is executed.

Answer (score -1):

You forget on `async execute(message)`
I think this code would work.

```
                const { MessageEmbed, Message } = require('discord.js');
            const fs = require('fs');
            const os = require('os');
            const config = require('../config.json');
            const CatLoggr = require('cat-loggr');
            
            // Functions
            const log = new CatLoggr();
            
            module.exports = {
                name: 'ban', // Command name (can be different from the file name)
                description: 'Bans a member.', // Command description displays in the help command
            
                async execute(message){ 
if(!message.guild.member(message.author).hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {return message.channel.send(..........
```

Comment: What would that change? OP exports an object with two keys, `name` and `description` and then tries to use an if statement in the middle of nowhere. Where should OP put this code? How would this solve the issue?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Im sorry i didnt mention what he did wrong and i started thinking about making new solutions of code. I edite message